# Infragistics Winforms Datagrid resizing columns hierarchical

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, infragistics

I'm using Infragistic's Winforms Datagrid from version 11.2.

I've put the following collections in the grid through it's Datasource property:

Person -1-----1..*- Order (So a 'person' can have 1 to many 'orders').

```
Person has the properties:
- Name
- Date of birth

Order has the properties:
- Order number
- Order date
```

Now the person's name is longer in size than the order number. I would like to size up the name column of person in Band # 0 and leave the order number column of order in Band # 1 small in size.

Can this be done and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your property:

```
grid.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowColSizing
```

it should be set to its default value  (not sure what is the default for your version) or set it manually to

```
AllowColSizing.Free
```